# How do I report a security issue to the Tor project?

Tags: security, information-leaks

I have found a security issue in Tor which allows for information leakage in certain scenarios. I went to report this to the Tor project, but found nothing more than a bug tracker, and no obvious documentation of a procedure to report significant security issues. Even web searches just led me back and forth between the bug tracker and Wikipedia, which is rather useless.

While I discovered that the issue I found is already in the bug tracker, it has been there for over a month with no apparent attention paid to it, and was not in any way marked as a security issue.

What is the best way to get Tor project members' attention for this issue? (And, in my case, to do so anonymously?)

Comment: I'd suggest emailing the tor-dev mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tor Project maintains several email accounts and [mailing lists](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/emailLists). The table at [administrative lists](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/emailLists#AdministrativeLists) shows the mailing list [tor-security](https://lists.torproject.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/tor-security). So tor-security@lists.torproject.org is the contact address you're looking for.

There is a trac entry which discusses a documented way to report vulnerabilities (see [#9186](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/9186)). It was discussed to create a OpenPGP key for the list tor-security, but as far as I see it there is none yet.

So when you want to report security issues you should send a private encrypted mail to Nick Mathewson, Andrea Shepard or Roger Dingledine using their GnuPG key.

Comment: Is there a public PGP key or something you can use to encrypt the email since you wouldn't want vulnerability information to be read by a middleman?